# Concat two strings and get the value in the clipboard

Tags: javascript

How to concat two strings and get the value in the clipboard?

```
var url = "www.myurl.123";
var img = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
var optionValue = url + " " + img;

  optionValue.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Img path: " + optionValue.value);
```

Comment: Did you try researching? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to input value

```js
var url = "www.myurl.123";
var img = document.getElementById("myInput2")
img.value = url + " " + img.value


img.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
alert("Img path: " + img.value);
```

```html
<input id="myInput2" value="image"/>
```